# Variable product stock in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stock

We have a Wordpress page, with variable products.

We have 2 different attributes we use for the variables. Rent/buy and Size.

I know I can pick whether i want the stock to be shared between all variations, or specific to all variations.

What I am looking for, is a way to have rent/buy share stock, but not the sizes.

Is there any way this is achievable without creating several products (or if that isn't possible, a product for buy and lease)?

Example: 'Red leather boots'

- Rent size 44
- Buy size 44
- Rent size 45
- Buy size 45
- Rent size 46
- Buy size 46

Whenever someone picks a size 45, i want that one to go down 1 in stock, both the rental and the one you can buy (but not the size 44 or 46).

Looking forward to any input!

Comment: Is there a clean way to use bundles? That avoids visually having 2 separate products, and keeps the possibility to switch from buy to lease and back?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in WooCommerce, but can be done easily with [Attribute Stock for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/attribute-stock-for-woocommerce/).

Instead of tracking stock at the *product/variation level* you can track an *attribute stock item* that is associated with both `Rent` and `Buy`. Then, whenever a product with one of these terms is purchased, the stock item will be reduced accordingly.

> **Disclaimer:** This is a plugin that I developed and recently released. Feedback is welcome!